# Understanding Kotlin React without any build tools

Tags: reactjs, kotlin

I am considering Kotlin for a large React project(migration from Oracle forms).
To be comfortable with Kotlin-React, I wanted to understand how I can use Kotlin-js compilers output without any build tools.
I am not very comfortable with JS and its ecosystem. So, this is just to make sure I understand things under the hood and prepared for any surprises later.
I am using create-kotlin-react-app to create the app.
For non-React-Kotlin code, I am able to do this by following this link
[working-with-modules](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/javascript/working-with-modules/working-with-modules.html)
But when using Kotlin-React compiled Javascript files, I am not able to figure out how to include Kotlin-react.js & kotlin-react-dome.js files in my html.
Here is my main.js

```js
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        'kotlin' : '../my-app/out/production/my-app/lib/kotlin',
        'kotlinx-html-js' : '../my-app/out/production/my-app/lib/kotlinx-html-js',
        'kotlin-extensions' : '../my-app/out/production/my-app/lib/build/classes/main/kotlin-extensions',
        'kotlin-react' : '../my-app/out/production/my-app/lib/build/classes/main/kotlin-react',
        'kotlin-react-dom' : '../my-app/out/production/my-app/lib/build/classes/main/kotlin-react-dom',
        'my-app': '../my-app/out/production/my-app/my-app'
    }
});

requirejs(["my-app"], function (myApp) {
    console.log(myApp)
});
```

Here, kotlin.js and my-app.js are loading fine. But, for kotlin-react.js etc, I am getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined".

Looks like kotlin-react.js etc libraries are not meant to be loaded by requireJs. Is it possible to use kotlin & react without any build tools?
If not, what is recommended method to achieve this with least amount of build tool magic?
Thanks a lot for your patience.

Comment: After asking the question here, I realized that I should have asked it to folks who built create-kotlin-react-app. So, I asked it there https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CRKA-99 And wonderful folks responded immediately. It seems that they are currently packaging kotlin-react js packages in CommonJs format. Looks like they can change it to package it in UMD format. That may resolve the issue. If anyone has any other suggestion, do let me know.